# Post Data to Webservice URL

Tags: objective-c, post, nsurlrequest

I have problem with my code for posting data to webservice.

Can someone please, tell me where I am going wrong.

I need to post three fields (doctorId-STRING, patientId. STRING, date-STRING) to this address:

> http://www.walter-dev.com/doctor/public/setTermin

How to make this right?

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&id_doktor=%@&id_pacijent=%@&datum=%@",@"iddoktora",@"idpacijenta",@"ovojedatum"];
NSData* postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

//You need to send the actual length of your data. Calculate the length of the post string.
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@”%d”,[postData length]];

//Create URLRequest object and initialize it.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

//Set the Url for which your going to send the data to that request
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.walter-dev.com/doctor/public/setTermin"]]];

//set HTTP method (POST)
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Set header field with lenght of the post data
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//I dont understand this line of code
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];


//Set httpbody of the urlrequest with string "post"
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

//Initialize object with urlRequest
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn)
{
    NSLog(@"Konekcija prema serveru je uspjela");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"NIJE USPJELA ");
}
```

Comment: This is not a question. Please add information about what problem you have and what you're searching for.

Comment: Also, please do not add tag names to your post titles.